# Eclipse issue proxy connection: unable to save secure preferences

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, proxy

[image]

Hi, as shown in screeshot, eclipse fails while saving the secure preferences file. Already tried to give 777 access to those folders (the fact that folder shown under Security -> secure storage -> Contents, as Storage Location didn't even exist, so I created it with a mkdir and I gave it 777 access.

But when, after filling, I click on apply than ok HTTP and HTTPS datas abour user and password are not saved!

Anyone?

Comment: Open the Error Log view, use the red X button to clear the log, then reproduce the preference saving problem. Go back to the Error Log view and see if anything is reported there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing the default secure storage location to something you **know** eclipse has write permissions for already. (Something like a sub-folder of your current workspace ?)

You can change the default location, by adding the following to your eclipse.ini :

```
...
-eclipse.keyring
c:\users\<userid>\.eclipse\secure.storage
...
```

Hope that helps !!

Comment: Indeed I tried it too... I solved it by installing Proxy+ so I putted in my password and username an provided localhost:4080 as proxy (a simple way to bypass but not really solve the problem :) )

Answer (score 4):

Known bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=286354#c1

> When I renamed file C:\Documents and Settings\.eclipse\org.eclipse.equinox.security\secure_storage
>   Saving the password worked again.

Answer (score 4):

window -> preferences-> general -> Security -> Secure storage-> ‘master password providers’

select ‘windows integration’ & click change password.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by installing Proxy+ so I putted in my password and username an provided localhost:4480 as proxy (a simple way to bypass but not really solve the problem :) )

Answer (score 1):

First, verify if Eclipse Proxy configured correctly:

Access Preferences via Window, Preferences Then expand General, then Security. Click on Secure Storage.

In the Contents tab, expand the [Default Secure Storage] list. Verify there are settings there for: org.eclipse.core.net.proxy.auth with settings for HTTP. You may also see you Git credentials.

You can attempt to recover your Eclipse Secure Storage password on the Password tab using Recover Password using the challenge prompts. If it fails, then you may need to delete your Secure Store to "reset" the secure storage.

select org.eclipse.equinox.secure.storage and click Delete.

You will then get prompted to set up your secure store and the password recovery challenge questions.